# removing missing elements from a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector `B=[1; 2; 1; 2; 3; 5; 6; 8; 9; 10]`

where the elements `a=[4 7]` are missing.

I would like to map B to a "continuous" vector like

```
B_map=[1; 2; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8]
```

removing the "missing" elements (4 7) and "scaling" the rest accordingly..

my problem is that depending on the number of missing elemenst (in this case 2) I have to scale the vector B of different amounts...

Comment: This seems ill-defined. What happens to the vector `[1;3;1;3]`?

Comment: What happened to 9 and 10 in `B`??

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out...

```
a = sort(a);

B_map = B;

for i = 1:numel(a)
    clear id_sub
    id_sub = find(B >= a(i));
    B_map(id_sub) = B_map(id_sub)-1;
end
```